# Disable horizontal scrolling function in mouse driver

Tags: windows, mouse, scrolling

I am using a simple bluetooth mouse (BM084 chipset) that has a well known bug when connected via USB. The problem is, that it keeps on scrolling sideways, although it does not contain any horizontal sensors. In Linux this bug has been fixed via a kernel patch.

My question: In Windows (Vista, 7, probably others) I am able to adjust the "speed" of horizontal scrolling, but it cannot be zero.  How can I completely disable this function or set the value to zero?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to prevent it from being moved horizontally at all (ie, only up and down)? At what X co-ordinate on the screen would this vertical line be?

Comment: Well, I want to stop horizontal scrollbars scrolling permanently right (in all windows applications).  But it really is not an application issue or dependending on coordinates, it is a hardware bug.  Some mice have a function, where you can push the scroll wheel to the left or the right.  The speed of horizontal scrolling can then be adjusted in windows just beneath the number of lines the mouse should scroll when turning the wheel.  This mouse type, when connected via USB wrongly reports that it has this function and permanently sends a signal to scroll right.

Comment: Ah, okay, it’s the *scroll-wheel*. Oh, well then I have no solutions for bad hardware, you can look in the manufacturer’s forums to see if there is a new driver or if someone has hacked something to work around the issue.